# print particular lines

Tags: python, grep

I have data in the following format:

```
     1     "hi"
     2     "hello"
     3 "abc"
     4-"def"
     5(-hjs
     6     "there" 
     abc"    "def"
     7     "there1"
```

A tab separates 1 and "hi". Another tab separates 2 and "hello" whereas between 3 and "abc" there is no such separation. Similarly for 4-"def" and 5(-hjs.

I want to delete all those lines where a tab does not separate a number and a string. I want my output to be of the following form.

```
     1     "hi"
     2     "hello"
     6     "there" 
     7     "there1"
```

I tried to store only those lines which contains numbers using grep '^ *[0-9]'(although it deletes abc, yet it is not able to delete the rest). However, it deletes all the lines. Is it possible to delete only specified lines using a linux command/python.

I tried to do in it python by checking whether there is a split or not..but split does not work for patterns of the form "abc"    def"

I am using a tab('\t') for tabulation..so how do i incorporate that...also can you please explain it a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) version supports the `perl` regular expression syntax, you can use it like:

```
grep -P '^\d+\t+\S+' infile
```

It matches from the beginning of line (`^`), a number (`\d+`) followed by one or more tabs (`\t+`) followed by a non-space character (`\S+`).

It yields:

```
1   "hi"
2   "hello"
6   "there" 
7   "there1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html):

```
s = """
1     "hi"
2     "hello"
3 "abc"
4-"def"
5(-hjs
6     "there" 
abc"    "def"
7     "there1"
"""

import re

for line in s.splitlines():
    if not line:
        continue # skip empty lines
    if re.match(r'^\d\t\S+', line):
        print line
```

Output:

```
>>> 
1     "hi"
2     "hello"
6     "there" 
7     "there1"
```

Explanation:

The regular expression pattern tries to match the line.

- `^`   : This means the start of the string (or line)
- `\d`  : This means match a single digit character
- `\t`  : This means match a tab character.
- `\S+` : This means match a non-white-space character at least once

You could change the regular expression to something like this: `r'^\d\s{4,}\S+'`

That adds a `\s{4,}` which means a white-space character at least 4 times (which is the default character length of most tabulations).

You could also combine them into a regular expression that can handle situations where tabs are converted to white-space: `r'^\d(\t|\s{4,})\S+'` This adds a group which will look for `\t` OR `\s{4,}`. which covers all your bases.

Comment: I am using a tab('\t') for tabulation..so how do i incorporate that...also can you please explain it a bit

Comment: Sorry but i am not using 5 white space characters rather i am using '\t' for tab

Comment: @JannatArora Okay, You can just use `\t` in the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep '^[0-9]*\s\{4\}'
```

(provided that you use 4 spaces for tabulation, as in the example you pasted).

Comment: I am using a tab('\t') for tabulation..so how do i incorporate that...also can you please explain it a bit

Comment: Does your `grep` in its basic regular expression syntax (BRE) support `\s`?

Comment: @Birei  But where do i incorporate '\t' in it

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+\t/' file
```

Prints only lines that starts with one or more number `[0-9]+` followed by a tab `\t`